How to dock and wake Windows laptop without opening it?
I want to plug in the dock (with the dongle for my wireless keyboard) and then wake up my Windows laptop with the keyboard. If the dock/dongle is connected to my laptop before the laptop goes to sleep, it will wake from the keyboard press; but if I plug in the dock/dongle after the computer is asleep, it won't wake up. Is there a Windows setting to allow it to still register a usb device while asleep? Sleep for my computer is S3 sleep.
Here is my current setup:
Logitech wireless keyboard -> Logi Bolt USB Receiver -> ThinkPad Dock -> Microsoft Audio Dock -> thunderbolt port on Lenovo T15g laptop
Other options that would be agreeable: the power button on the lenovo dock (it doesn't get the signal through the microsoft dock) or switching the keyboard to the bluetooth connection with the laptop (but it doesn't connect while the laptop is asleep).
